# Handling Backlight of navigation button : WP8

Tags: windows-phone-8, windows-phone

I wanted to know if there is anyway I can handle backlight of windows phone buttons (back, windows and search). If possible I wish to change its level according to my app UI.

Answer (score 1):

You can't control those backlights. They are only controlled by the battery saver. If ur device is in battery saver mode then they are off and vice versa. You cant change that functionality. Sorry

Answer (score 0):

There is no mechanism to control those backlights.